# Ensuring safe file access in both Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, file

My team is doing Java Development on Windows, while our production server is running in Linux.  We're using a lot of resource files in our projects, and because Windows and Linux use different file systems, it can happen that a file can be found in our development environment, but not in our production environment, e.g. "path/to/file/Filename.txt" can be found in Windows using the path "path/to/file/filename.txt", but the same path cannot find the desired file in Linux.

I'd like to make it so that anytime the file system is accessed in testing scope, it validates that the path will work in the Linux environment.  I've figured out that a good test is to make sure that the absolute path is equal to the canonical path [`file.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getCanonicalPath())`], but how can I make sure that this is checked everytime a file is accessed?  I've thought about creating a new FileSystemProvider and overriding the default FileSystemProvider, but this is very complicated.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you mean something like [jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs)? It has [configuration options](https://google.github.io/jimfs/releases/1.1/api/docs/com/google/common/jimfs/Configuration.html) for different operating systems.

Comment: It might work.  But unfortunately I don't have the ability to bring in another third party dependency.

Comment: Well then you could also [enable case sensitive file and folder names](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/) for the specific folders on your windows dev machine.